# Text not updating

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I have two classes;- one called Form1.cs and another called NoteThreader.cs and here are the contents of both classes:

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace HitMachine
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void updateText(string theText)
    {
        label1.Text = theText;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XML.LoadMP3.loadFile(XML.XmlParser.ParseDocument("music"));
        Threading.NoteThreader.createTimer();
    }
  }
}
```

NoteThreader.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace HitMachine.Threading
    {
        public class NoteThreader
        {
            public static Thread createTimer()
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(threadDeligation);
                t.Start();

                return t;
            }

            public static int time = 0;

            static void threadDeligation()
            {
                for (; ; )
                {
                    Form1 a = new Form1();
                    a.updateText(time);
                    time++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code runs without any exceptions or errors; however it doesn't update the text. I'm guessing it's because the thread that is calling the method is different to the thread updating the text?

I've tried to invoke it but haven't been able to do so. I ran a MessageBox in the threadDeligation and that worked.

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint and step through the code at the point where it's supposed to update the text?

Comment: Nope, I'm not too good with understanding breakpoints. I added a breakpoint and theText variable = "hello" however it just doesn't seem to be updating the label1.Text.

Comment: I'd suggest starting off with something simpler than threading, if you are having trouble with breakpoints.

Comment: I can't, I don't want my application to lag so it's pretty vital that I use multiple threads. The breakpoint seemed to suggest that it was a 'Non-Public member'?

Comment: Honestly, learning how to debug and use breakpoints will be infinitely better for you in the long run than the insistence of learning threading. Threading is good to know, but it's more of an advanced skill, where as breakpoints are basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a number of issues here.  First the obvious one that other answers have mentioned.  You're creating new instances of `Form1` and calling its methods, and consequently modifying its label.  You're not modifying the form that is being show to the user; it is unchanged.

If you were to get a hold of the instance of the form you were using, then you'd run into the problem that you're modifying the form from a different thread.  That's not allowed.  In winform programming you're only allowed to access `Control` objects from the thread that created them; they will error otherwise.

To solve that you could invoke to the main UI thread to do the update.  But then you're now in a position where you're sending commands to update the label as fast as your computer can possibly send them.  That's...very, very very fast.  So fast that the screen won't be able to update at all; you'll start lagging, or even freezing up, due to the sheer volume of commands you're sending.

It seems you want to create some sort of makeshift clock where you increment a number ever X interval of time.  Let's say once a second (but you could easily change it to ever 10 milliseconds, or whatever).  To do something ever X interval of time we'll want to use a `Timer`.

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

private int time = 0;
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = time.ToString();
    time++;
}
```

If, rather than performing an action every X interval of time what you're really trying to do here, despite your naming conventions, is do some productive work and update the user interface based on the progress of your work, then it's a  different problem.  One good option here is to use the `Progress` class to update the UI with the progress of some non-UI task.  It could look something like this:

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Progress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(updateText);
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => NoteThreader.DoWork(progress));
    thread.Start();
}

public class NoteThreader
{
    public static void DoWork(IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);//placeholder for real work
            progress.Report(i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which references am I supposed to make in the header? (but thank you very much!)

Comment: @Jarrod For anything that doesn't resolve just right click on it and look at the options in the "Resolve" menu and have it add the needed `using` statements for you.

Comment: I don't seem to have a resolve menu - well I do, but it's only offering for making a new class or method

Comment: @Jarrod Then just Google the class name(s) to see what namespace they're in.  The MSDN pages will have that information.

Comment: No such namespace could be found

Comment: @Jarrod What version of .NET are you using?  It was added in 4.5.

Comment: I saw that so I tried to download it and it say's I'm already running 4.5

Comment: @Jarrod And in your project settings do you have this project set to use it in the build tab?

Comment: It only says 4 in the build tab

Answer (score 2):

In your `threadDeligation` method you are creating a new instance of `Form1` every time your loop executes. This will not change the text in the instance of `Form1` that you are looking at.

You will need to pass the correct instance of `Form1` to the `createTimer` method (and then pass it on to the `threadDeligation` method).

You could go about it like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XML.LoadMP3.loadFile(XML.XmlParser.ParseDocument("music"));
    Threading.NoteThreader.createTimer(this);
}
```

And then:

```
public static Thread createTimer(Form1 theForm)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => threadDeligation(theForm));
    t.Start();
   return t;
}

public static int time = 0;

static void threadDeligation(Form1 theForm)
{
    for (; ; )
    {
         theForm.updateText(time);
         time++;
    }
}
```

This should give you the general idea of how to pass objects around in your code,
but it will **NOT** work since updating UI elements from a non-ui thread is not supported. You will need to use the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! But now I'm getting 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

Comment: Yes, I was going to comment on that, I just wanted to show the general way to pass the reference correctly. When manipulating UI elements you generally want to use the `BackgroundWorker` class.

Comment: So I should switch from using the threads and use the BackgroundWorker instead?

Comment: @Jarrod No, you shouldn't.

Comment: Servy, how should I go about doing it then?

Comment: @Jarrod He should be using a `Timer` here, based on what it appears he's trying to do.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is record the time then I was going to make another thread that imports all these notes in from an XML file

Comment: @Jarrod Ah, well then that's a rather different problem from what your example shows.  In that case a BGW is one valid option, among others.

Comment: Thanks for that, will I have to make the backgroundworker in Form1

Answer (score 1):

```
for (; ; )
{
    Form1 a = new Form1();
    a.updateText(time);
    time++;
}
```

1. New `Form1` object will be created on every iteration.
2. Where is `a.Show();`?

If you want to display timer's value, you should keep reference to appropriate `Form1` object.

Comment: Maybe that's the wrong way to use this then, but what I was trying to do was to create a link to access the static void from the NoteThreader.cs to the Form1.cs, so I thought calling it like that would be the way to do so?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Jarrod:see Klaus answer.